# General definition of a standing wave

Tags: waves, energy-conservation, poynting-vector

Question ["What is standing wave?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/268454/what-is-a-standing-wave) has already been asked. Intuitively we all know what it is, but how would we define such a wave in the most general way: for arbitrary geometry, dispersion, dimensions, nature, etc.?

My suggestion: standing wave is a wave that does not carry energy flux.

Comment: In a similar manner I guess something could be said about its time invariance.

Comment: my suggestion: it is a product ot a spacial part and a periodic function of time, possibly with some condition on the spacial part

Comment: *My suggestion: standing wave is a wave that does not carry energy flux* - Yes, or more formally if you take any area element the average energy flux through that element is zero. Isn't this a standard wave to define a standing wave?

Comment: @JohnRennie I would think so, but this is not explicitly spelled in textbooks - not in the basic textbooks at least - see, e.g., [this thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/243171/247642)