# Can two semi-infinite plane waves undergo perfectly constructive interference?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation, laser, interference, superposition

This is building off of a question I asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/434024/).

When discussing the linked problem with some friends, the consensus seemed to be that the reason two identical semi-infinite plane waves cannot undergo perfect constructive interference is because their non-infinite spatial extent means they necessarily cannot be monochromatic, and so they cannot perfectly constructively interfere everywhere.

While this seems logical, I feel there is an assumption here that shouldn't be taken for granted: this assumes that the spatial distribution of frequencies cannot be the same for both waves. Is this the case? Or is it possible to generate two coherent semi-infinite beams whose spatial frequency distributions are perfectly in phase?

This question is, I believe, equivalent to asking if two identical semi-infinite plane waves can perfectly constructively interfere. In the linked question you can see my energy-based argument as to why I expect it is not possible. I'm looking for a more rigorous workthrough.

Comment: Is a semi infinite plane wave even a valid solution of Maxwell’s equations?

Comment: @Dale it is valid. It's easy to see this: just consider an initial state where a superposition of infinite plane waves forms a semi-infinite plane wave (all the wave vectors in the superposition point the same direction). Then, since vacuum is dispersionless, this sem-infinite wave will move with $c$ as a rigid structure.

Comment: @Dale : Yes. The Maxwell wave equations are just that: wave equations, and identical in form to those describing (small) waves on a tense string, or on the surface of water. More specifically, they are "the" (classical, linear) wave equation. Thus, any phenomenon we can observe with one, we can observe with the other. And a "semi-infinite plane wave" is a solution of "the" wave equation.

Comment: Please define *semi-infinite plane wave*.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain that a semi infinite plane wave is a valid solution to Maxwell’s equations. However, let us instead consider a general wave that is a solution to Maxwell’s equations. If you make another wave which has complete constructive interference with the first wave then you will add the two fields together, resulting in a double field everywhere. This also includes doubling the sources.

If you double the fields then according to Poynting’s theorem you have four times as much energy. His seems to be a violation of the conservation of energy. However, in fact it is not. The energy in the waves is indeed four times as great, but in order to produce such a wave you must have doubled the sources as well. So you doubled the E field and you doubled J. Then by Poynting’s theorem you have quadrupled the work.

So yes, the field contains four times as much energy, but it also requires four times as much energy to produce. The mistake is in believing that it only requires double the work to produce the double field.

Comment: You must double each of the two sources? Why?

Comment: If you have complete constructive interference everywhere then by the various uniqueness theorems you must have the same sources. Therefore all sources are doubled

Comment: Two input sources. Exactly identical. Each with a field strength E corresponding to a power E^2. So the total input power is 2E^2. By superposition, output beam has field strength 2E and so a power 4E^2 - twice the input power. This is the issue. I don't find your reasoning to be rigorous or convincing

Comment: Yes, EXACTLY identical including their location. If they are not exactly identical including location then you will not get complete constructive interference everywhere. So E is doubled and I is doubled and therefore by Poynting’s theorem the work (input power) is quadrupled as is the field energy and flux.

Comment: This answer is rather unsatisfactory. ***Why*** do you need to double the sources? And what happens if you have complete destructive interference? What happens to the energy?

Comment: “Why do you need to double the sources?” Because you specified complete constructive interference everywhere. There is no other way to achieve that. Your sources must be completely identical including the location.

Comment: You keep saying the sources need to be doubled, but you’re basically saying they need to be doubled because they need to be doubled. Can you actually provide a reason for why that’s the case, using some rigor that doesn’t just require us to trust that you’re correct?

Comment: You specified complete constructive interference everywhere. That means that at every point in space and every moment in time E1 = E2 and B1 = B2, where the subscripts 1 and 2 identify the original field and the constructively interfering field respectively. Because of the uniqueness theorem that also implies that rho1 = rho2 and J1 = J2. The total E field is therefore Etotal = E1 + E2 = 2*E1 and the total current density is Jtotal = J1 + J2 = 2*J1. The total input power is therefore Ptotal = 2*E1 2*J1 = 4*P1

Comment: @Dale: You're just saying what you said in your answer again. I think the OP wants more details.

Comment: Like what? I don’t know how to be more specific than pointing to the two specific theorems that require this result. How could it be more clear?

Comment: @Riley Jacob suppose I have a dipole antenna at the origin oscillating at 1 MHz. If I wish to make a wave with perfect constructive interference everywhere, what source would I need?

Comment: @Dale:  Suppose I'm trying to teach you relativity, and a student shows me the Michelson-Morley experiment, and claims that you can use it to actually measure absolute motion. Does saying "it's going to fail because motion is relative" help them understand relativity? I don't think so. While that's a perfectly true statement, it's completely useless pedagogically.

Comment: The OP is trying to understand quantum mechanics. He's asking the question "what happens if I try to make complete constructive interference with just twice the energy by putting two sources on the same spot?" You're quoting a theorem that this is impossible. The OP already knows that; he didn't need you to tell him. His question, the answer to which might help him understand quantum mechanics better, is: **Exactly what goes wrong?**

Comment: But I explained that part too. I showed that putting two sources at the same spot requires 4 times the energy, not twice! Putting two sources at the same spot (as you must do for complete constructive interference) doubles E as well as J which quadruples the input power.

Comment: But how does the second source ***know*** that it's sitting exactly on top of the first source (and not, say, an infinitesimal distance to one side)? This is what I mean by "exactly what goes wrong?"

Comment: J is non-zero right on the first source and zero just off the first source.

Comment: @Dale: Don't physical quantities have to vary continuously?

Comment: Not in general, no. Current density in particular will be discontinuous in a wire vs immediately outside the wire.

Comment: What if the sources have a distance of a wavelength between them, and we only require perfect interference where the waves overlap?

Comment: @Ruslan Then we get constructive interference in that region and at least partially destructive interference elsewhere. The higher energy density in one region is compensated for by lower energy density elsewhere such that globally energy is conserved.