# Where does the extra energy stored in the electric field come from when two perpendicular EM waves constructively interfere?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, waves, energy-conservation, interference

Consider two EM waves, the first one moving the positive x-axis and the second one moving the positive y-axis such that the electric field component of the two EM wave is in the z-axis.

Let the electric field of the first wave be $z=E_1=E_{0}\sin(\omega t-kx)$ and the electric field of the second wave be $z=E_2=E_{0}\sin(\omega t-ky)$.
[image]

We can see that the two waves meet at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. At this point $E_1+E_2=2E_{0}\sin(\omega t)$ so there is always constructive interference at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. The energy stored in a electric field is square of its amplitude so due to constructive interference energy becomes double at this point.

So my question is, as there is no destructive inteference where does this extra energy stored in the electric field due to constructive inteference come from?

Comment: this MIT video might interest you, where it deals with  laser beams  interfering https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-006-video-demonstrations-in-lasers-and-optics-spring-2008/demonstrations-in-physical-optics/destructive-interference-2014-where-does-the-light-go/

Comment: Hint: do electric waves exist on their own? :)

Comment: @jensenpaull I have considered the effect of magnetic field. If the magnetic field amplitude of the two waves are equal say $B_0$, the resultant would be $\sqrt{2}B_0$(magnetic fields are perpendicular to each other), so there will be no change in the energy stored in the magnetic field.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/196650/question-about-intensity-of-em-waves look at the accepted answer